# How to iterate multiple cross-references?

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML source specifies cross-references in `linkGrp`. Based on those
cross-references specified by the @target attribute, I need to group the
values of the `s` elements. If the target attribute contains one-to-one
reference, the code I have works well as follows:

```
<DIV>
    <div id="e">
        <s id="e1">AAAAA</s>
        <s id="e2">BBBBB</s>
        <s id="e3">CCCCC</s>
    </div>
    <div id="fr">
        <s id="fr1">DDDDD</s>
        <s id="fr2">EEEEE</s>
        <s id="fr3">FFFFF</s>
    </div>
    <linkGrp type="alignment" domains="e fr">
        <link target="#e1 #fr1"/>
        <link target="#e2 #fr3"/>
        <link target="#e3 #fr2"/>
    </linkGrp>
</DIV>
```

The requested HTML output I get is this:

```
*AAAAA
DDDDD

*BBBBB
FFFFF

*CCCCC
EEEEE
```

To get this result I use the following XSLT code:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="linkId" match="s" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:template match="/DIV">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Test</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="link">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('linkId',substring-before(substring-after(@target, '#'), ' '))"/>
                <br/>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('linkId',substring-after(@target, ' #'))"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="div"/>
    <xsl:template match="s"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:message terminate="no">
            WARNING: Unmatched element: <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </xsl:message>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, my XSLT code does not work that well when I add more cross-references for one @target in the `link` elements as this:

```
<DIV>
    <div id="e">
        <s id="e1">AAAAA</s>
        <s id="e2">BBBBB</s>
        <s id="e3">CCCCC</s>
    </div>
    <div id="fr">
        <s id="fr1">DDDDD</s>
        <s id="fr2">EEEEE</s>
        <s id="fr3">FFFFF</s>
    </div>
    <linkGrp type="alignment" domains="e fr">
        <link target="#e1 #fr1"/>
        <link target="#e2 #fr3 #fr1 #fr2"/>
        <link target="#e3 #fr2 #fr3"/>
    </linkGrp>
</DIV>
```

With multiple cross-references in the XML source, my XSLT code does not fetch
any match. And I need my code to retrieve all matches specified in the `@target`
attribute. Can anyone point the mistake in my XSLT code or offer alternative
solution?

Comment: Your post is hard to read. Please use the code formatting feature (by indenting source text with 4 spaces) instead of trying to do the markup yourself. Also, please repair your caps lock key :)

Comment: @Tim, what's wrong with caps lock key?

Comment: Don't use all-caps in a title. IT LOOKS LIKE YOU ARE SHOUTING!

Comment: @John, no shouting, just using the TEI-compliant element

Comment: I meant that you used all upper case in the title of this question.

Comment: @John, then it was calling for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With xslt-1.0 you may use a recursive template call to split up the ids.
Try something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="linkId" match="s" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:template match="/DIV">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Test</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="link">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <xsl:call-template name="findtarget">
                    <xsl:with-param name="targets" select="@target" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="findtarget">
        <xsl:param name="targets" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($targets, ' ')">
                <xsl:call-template name="findtarget">
                    <xsl:with-param name="targets" select="substring-before($targets,' ')" />
                </xsl:call-template>
                <br/>
                <xsl:call-template name="findtarget">
                    <xsl:with-param name="targets" select="substring-after($targets,' ')" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('linkId',substring-after($targets, '#'))"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div"/>
    <xsl:template match="s"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:message terminate="no">
            WARNING: Unmatched element: <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </xsl:message>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
                     WARNING: Unmatched element: linkGrp
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>



                <ul><li>AAAAA<br>DDDDD</li></ul>
                <ul><li>BBBBB<br>FFFFF<br>DDDDD<br>EEEEE</li></ul>
                <ul><li>CCCCC<br>EEEEE<br>FFFFF</li></ul>

</body>
</html>
```

An alternative solution may be to use the xpath function `id()`.  But to make it work your XML need to have a DTD DOCTYPE.
Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE DIV  [
<!ATTLIST s
  id     ID    #REQUIRED
>
]>
<DIV>
    <div id="e">
        <s id="e1">AAAAA</s>
        <s id="e2">BBBBB</s>
        <s id="e3">CCCCC</s>
    </div>
    <div id="fr">
        <s id="fr1">DDDDD</s>
        <s id="fr2">EEEEE</s>
        <s id="fr3">FFFFF</s>
    </div>
    <linkGrp type="alignment" domains="e fr">
        <link target="#e1 #fr1"/>
        <link target="#e2 #fr3 #fr1 #fr2"/>
        <link target="#e3 #fr2 #fr3"/>
    </linkGrp>
</DIV>
```

With this XML your link template could be change as following:

```
<xsl:template match="link">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <xsl:for-each select="id(translate(@target,'#', ''))">
                <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
                    <br/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </li>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks for solution! It works, yet it returns something extra for me - that is, your template also returns all the matches in one line followed afterwards by the matches shown in your output example. Could you also pls talk me through your choice to combine the call-template and with-param elements?

Comment: @hr117, the 2nd solution is smart and elegant. Thanx! Could you pls attend to my question related to your 1st solution.

Comment: Somehow I don't understand. You don't get the right output? If you like to have additional "end of line" add `<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>`. The call-template  calls it self recursively with the string before the first space and with the string after the first space. If there is no space remaining it generate the output for the id.

Comment: @hr117, in both cases, the output has an additional line containing all the values of <s> as this <p>AAAAA BBBBB CCCCC DDDDD EEEEE FFFFF</p> before the list of matches. And then the rest of the output is OK. With this small XML source, it's not a problem but in case of a large XML doc, this duplication in the output would cause a problem.

Comment: @gabrielemucho I do not see how this should happen. If you use the above stylesheet the empty templates for `div` and `s` (`<xsl:template match="div"/>,<xsl:template match="s"/>`) should prevent any output for `s`. But perhaps it would be even better to change the xsl:apply-templates in `boody` to  `<xsl:apply-templates select="link/linkGrp" />`

Comment: @hr117, I see, a trivial mistake of mine, forgot to add templates matching <div> and <s> at the low level of the document, which generated the unwanted line. It's solved! Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: @gabrielemucho Glad I could help. By the way if this was what you are looking for, please consider to mark the answer as accepted.