# How to group the element values by using the explicit cross-references?

Tags: xml, xslt

How to group the values of the elements <seg> in the XML source, using the explicit cross-references created by the @corresp attributes?

```
<DIV>
<div id="fr">
  <seg id="fr_1" corresp="#en_1">abc</seg>
  <seg id="fr_2" corresp="#en_2 #en3">def</seg>
  <seg id="fr_3" corresp="#en_3 #en_4">ghi</seg>
  <seg id="fr_4" corresp="#en_4 #en_5">jkl</seg>
  <seg id="fr_5" corresp="#en_6">mno</seg>
</div>
<div id="en">
  <seg id="en_1" corresp="#fr_1">ab</seg>
  <seg id="en_2" corresp="#fr_1 #fr_2">cde</seg>
  <seg id="en_3" corresp="#fr_2 #fr_3">fg</seg>
  <seg id="en_4" corresp="#fr_3 #fr_4">hij</seg>
  <seg id="en_5" corresp="#fr_4">kl</seg>
  <seg id="en_6" corresp="#fr_5">mno</seg>
</div>
</DIV>
```

The XSLT-transformed output should look as follows:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>abc<br/>ab</li>
    <li>abc<br/>cde</li>
    <li>def<br/>cde</li>
    <li>def<br/>fg</li>
    <li>ghi<br/>fg</li>
    <li>ghi<br/>hij</li>
    <li>jkl<br/>hij</li>
    <li>jkl<br/>kl</li>
    <li>mno<br/>mno</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks!

@Jirka, here is a similar input but with further elements nested within the  element. And the corresp attribute defines cross-references among these new elements . The modified input looks as follows:

```
<DIV>
<div id="fr">
  <seg id="fr_1"><w id="fr1" corresp="#en2">AA</w> <w id="fr2" corresp="#en3">BB</w>, <w id="fr3" corresp="#en1">CC</w>.</seg>
  <seg id="fr_2"><w id="fr1" corresp="#en1">DD</w> <w id="fr2" corresp="#en3">EE</w>?</seg>
  <seg id="fr_3"><w id="fr1" corresp="#en1">FF</w> <w id="fr2" corresp="#en3">GG</w><w id="fr3" corresp="#en2">HH</w></seg>
</div>
<div id="en">
<seg id="en_1"><w id="en1" corresp="#fr3">AX</w><w id="en2" corresp="#fr1">BX</w><w id="en3" corresp="#fr2">CX</w></seg>
 <seg id="en_2"><w id="en1" corresp="#fr1">DX</w><w id="en2" corresp="#en0">EX</w><w id="en3" corresp="#en2">FX</w></seg> 
 <seg id="en_3"><w id="en1" corresp="#fr1">HX</w> <w id="en2" corresp="#en3">IX</w><w id="en3" corresp="#en2">JX</w>.</seg>
</div>
```

And the output needed should look as follows:

```
<div>
 <ol>
  <li><w>AA</w> : <w>BX</w><br/><w>BB</w> : <w>AX</w><br/> </li>
  <li><w>DD</w> : <w>DX</w><w>EE</w> : <w>FX</w><br/><br/> </li>
  <li><w>FF</w> :<w>HX</w><br/> <w>GG</w> :<w>JX</w><br/><w>HH</w>:<w>IX</w><br/></li>
 </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this slight  adaption of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17580820/2115381) to your last question:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="kSegId" match="seg" use="@id"/>

    <xsl:template match="/DIV">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="div[@id='en']/seg"/>
                </ul>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="seg">
                <xsl:call-template name="findtarget">
                    <xsl:with-param name="targets" select="@corresp" />
                </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="findtarget">
        <xsl:param name="targets" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($targets, ' ')">
                <xsl:call-template name="findtarget">
                    <xsl:with-param name="targets" select="substring-before($targets,' ')" />
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:call-template name="findtarget">
                    <xsl:with-param name="targets" select="substring-after($targets,' ')" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <li>

                    <xsl:value-of select="key('kSegId',substring-after($targets, '#'))"/>
                    <br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </li>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>abc<br/>ab</li>
      <li>abc<br/>cde</li>
      <li>def<br/>cde</li>
      <li>def<br/>fg</li>
      <li>ghi<br/>fg</li>
      <li>ghi<br/>hij</li>
      <li>jkl<br/>hij</li>
      <li>jkl<br/>kl</li>
      <li>mno<br/>mno</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @hr117, I somehow get the entire output in <li></li> as a single string...?

Answer (score 0):

Following xslt could work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/DIV">
        <div>
            <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="div[@id = 'fr']/seg" />
            </ul>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="seg[../@id = 'fr']">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id" />
        <xsl:variable name="text" select="." />

        <xsl:for-each select="//div[@id = 'en']/seg[contains(@corresp, $id)]">
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
                <br />
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transform my input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DIV>
    <div id="fr">
        <seg id="fr_1" corresp="#en_1">abc</seg>
        <seg id="fr_2" corresp="#en_2 #en3">def</seg>
        <seg id="fr_3" corresp="#en_3 #en_4">ghi</seg>
        <seg id="fr_4" corresp="#en_4 #en_5">jkl</seg>
        <seg id="fr_5" corresp="#en_6">mno</seg>
    </div>
    <div id="en">
        <seg id="en_1" corresp="#fr_1">ab</seg>
        <seg id="en_2" corresp="#fr_1 #fr_2">cde</seg>
        <seg id="en_3" corresp="#fr_2 #fr_3">fg</seg>
        <seg id="en_4" corresp="#fr_3 #fr_4">hij</seg>
        <seg id="en_5" corresp="#fr_4">kl</seg>
        <seg id="en_6" corresp="#fr_5">mno</seg>
    </div>
</DIV>
```

Into this output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ul>
        <li>abc<br/>ab</li>
        <li>abc<br/>cde</li>
        <li>def<br/>cde</li>
        <li>def<br/>fg</li>
        <li>ghi<br/>fg</li>
        <li>ghi<br/>hij</li>
        <li>jkl<br/>hij</li>
        <li>jkl<br/>kl</li>
        <li>mno<br/>mno</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you needed html output than you had to change xsl:output declaration and also add some html tags to the input.

Comment: thanks for a solution. I tried out your code and it indeed returns the output I need, yet it retrieves all data as a single string. Cannot nail the culprit...

Comment: Strange... Is your input exactly same as you presented in your question? Aren't any other elements there for example?

Comment: I've spotted one mistake in the input here: <seg id="fr_2" corresp="#en_2 #en3">def</seg>, which should be <seg id="fr_2" corresp="#en_2 #en_3">def</seg>. That is, changing #en3 into #en_3. But this should not be the problem...

Comment: Right, it shouldn't be that problem. I added some more information about my input and output file... might be, they are different from yours in some aspects.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I overlooked changing the output method. It works perfectly well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have a similar input but the corresp attributes are nested deeper in the input structure. Could you have a look at it and advise how to adapt previous XSLT to get a different output?

Comment: What does "deeper" exactly mean? DIV element is not a root element or ... ?

Comment: pls see the input and output related to this question in your edited answer

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what should be done in second input. At first `<li>` I don't know why BB is associated with AX (I would expect CX) and also I don't why CC is not in the output. Actually I think this should be  rather a new question.

Comment: The idea is to follow the linking defined by the corresp attribute. To me this is a related question but perhaps you are right suggesting it should be posted as a separate one, which I did. But thanks for all help.